# How to stop animation at a particular keyframe

Tags: three.js, blender

I am very new to three.js and blender, I am trying to have a 3D image of a robot arm that rotates from 0 to 180 and vice versa,I have used blender2.8.1 for animation and have exported the glb file and called it in an html file with three.js module, till here things are fine but now I want to stop it at some degree let's say if I give in the value 30 then the robot arm should move by 30, and if the previous state was at 60 then it should add 30 and move to 90. The referred example is https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_morph

Can someone please help?
Thank you in advance.
Here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #222;
            }
            a {
                color: #2fa1d6;
            }
            p {
                max-width: 600px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                padding: 0 2em;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

            import Stats from '../examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
            import { GUI } from '../examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';

            import { GLTFLoader } from '../examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

            var container, stats, clock, gui, mixer, actions, activeAction, previousAction;
            var camera, scene, renderer, model, face;
            var api = { state: 'middle' };
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {
                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 120, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 100 );
                camera.position.set( 50, 30, -70 );
                camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xe0e0e0 );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xe0e0e0, 20, 100 );
                clock = new THREE.Clock();
                // lights
                var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
                light.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
                scene.add( light );
                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0, 20, 10 );
                scene.add( light );
                // ground
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                scene.add( mesh );
                var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 40, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
                grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
                grid.material.transparent = true;
                scene.add( grid );
                // model
                var loader = new GLTFLoader();
                loader.load( 'robo.glb', function ( gltf ) {
                    model = gltf.scene;
                    scene.add( model );
                    createGUI( model, gltf.animations );
                }, undefined, function ( e ) {
                    console.error( e );
                } );
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;
                renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
                // stats
                stats = new Stats();
                //container.appendChild( stats.dom );
            }
            function createGUI( model, animations ) {
                var states = [ 'negative', 'positive'];

                gui = new GUI();
                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
                actions = {};
                for ( var i = 0; i < animations.length; i ++ ) {
                    var clip = animations[ i ];
                    var action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
                    actions[ clip.name ] = action;
                    if ( states.indexOf( clip.name ) >= 4 ) {
                        action.clampWhenFinished = true;
                        action.loop = THREE.LoopOnce;
                    }
                }
                // states
                var statesFolder = gui.addFolder( 'States' );
                var clipCtrl = statesFolder.add( api, 'state' ).options( states );
                clipCtrl.onChange( function () {
                    fadeToAction( api.state, 1 );
                } );
                statesFolder.close();
                // emotes
                //var emoteFolder = gui.addFolder( 'Emotes' );
                                }
                function restoreState() {
                    mixer.removeEventListener( 'finished', restoreState );
                    fadeToAction( api.state, 0 );
                }

                    face = model.getObjectByName( 'Head_2' );
                var expressions = Object.keys( face.morphTargetDictionary );
                var expressionFolder = gui.addFolder( 'Expressions' );
                for ( var i = 0; i < expressions.length; i ++ ) {
                    expressionFolder.add( face.morphTargetInfluences, i, 0, 1, 0.01 ).name( expressions[ i ] );
                }
                activeAction = actions[ 'middle' ];
                    activeAction.play();
                //expressionFolder.open();

            function fadeToAction( name, duration ) {
                previousAction = activeAction;
                activeAction = actions[ name ];
                if ( previousAction !== activeAction ) {
                    previousAction.fadeOut( duration );
                }
                activeAction
                    .reset()

                    .fadeIn( duration )
                                        .setDuration(10)
                    .play();
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
            //
            function animate() {
                var dt = clock.getDelta();
                if ( mixer ) mixer.update( dt );
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                stats.update();
            }

        </script>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: did you by any chance found a way to solve it?

Comment: Nope, I later switched to AWS Sumerian because of not being able to explore three.js completely, give it a try it's pretty cool

Comment: You might be able to use startAt() and then use the .stop() method :
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.startAt